# Asynchrony issues with wallet creation (monero-javascript)

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, synchronization, wallet, javascript

I'm creating my monero **wallets** using the **`monero-javascript`** javascript library and this is the code I use

```
async function createWalletFull(password, mnemonic, id, network) {
  try {
    let wallet
    if (network == "TESTNET") {
      wallet = await monerojs.createWalletFull({
        networkType: MoneroNetworkType.TESTNET,
        password: password,
        mnemonic: mnemonic,
        serverUri: "http://127.0.0.1:28081",
        path: <path>
      });
    } else {
      wallet = await monerojs.createWalletFull({
        networkType: MoneroNetworkType.MAINNET,
        password: password,
        mnemonic: mnemonic,
        serverUri: "http://127.0.0.1:28081",
        path: <path>
      });
    }
    
    return wallet
    
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Error during creation of the wallet: " + error.message);
  }
}

async function createAddressMonero(coin, path, child, network, id_utente,index=0) {
  const privateKey = child.privateKey.toString("hex");
  
  let wallet;
  const mnemonic = mnemonicGen.mn_encode(
    privateKey,
    "english"
  );

  if (network == "TESTNET") {
    wallet = await createWalletFull("password", mnemonic, id_utente, "TESTNET")
  } else {
    wallet = await createWalletFull("password", mnemonic, id_utente, "MAINNET")
  }

  console.log("\n---------Monero---------\n");
  let primaryAddress = await wallet.getPrimaryAddress();
  let publicSpendKey = await wallet.getPublicSpendKey();
  let publicViewKey = await wallet.getPublicViewKey();
  let privateSpendKey = await wallet.getPrivateSpendKey();
  let privateViewKey = await wallet.getPrivateViewKey();
  await saveOnDB() //function to save on DB the wallet 
}

async function generation(Masternode, network) {

    Object.keys(COIN_TYPE).forEach(async (coin) => {
    const path = `m/44'/${COIN_TYPE[coin]}'/${ACCOUNT_INDEX}'/${CHANGE_INDEX}/0`;
    const child = Masternode.derivePath(path);
    const privateKey = child.privateKey.toString("hex");
    const publicKey = child.publicKey.toString("hex");

console.log("child Private key:", privateKey);
console.log("child Public key:", publicKey);

// other code esecuted...

//address creation for MONERO Blockchain 
if (coin === "XMR") {
  await createAddressMonero(coin, path, child, network);
}
```

});
}

it's as if await didn't work with the  **`createWalletFull`** function, as the Monero worker intervenes and immediately returns nullifying await. Is there any solution to make createWalletFull asynchronous?

While executing the program, the end of the execution of this function is not waited.

Comment: `await` in this context is the wallet being created, not that it has synchronized with the network or something else. Hence, what are you expecting `await` to be waiting on?

Comment: I'll explain better:

In one function I perform several operations (among these operations is the creation of monero wallets as you see them in the question), once the operations are performed, I print it and return true.

The problem is that the function, despite being set as asynchronous, returns true without waiting for the correct execution of the monero wallet and its assignment to the wallet variable.

Comment: "without waiting for the correct execution of the monero wallet" I don't understand what you mean by this. Are you saying the wallet is not created? Perhaps expand your example code to show how/where something is not working as you intend/expect.

Comment: the await keyword is used to suspend the execution of the function until a promise is resolved.

It doesn't work with monero's createWalletFull feature.

Instead of waiting for assignment "wallet= monerojs.createWalletFull"
Instead of waiting for the "wallet= monerojs.createWalletFull" assignment, the code proceeds as if that "await" wasn't there

Comment: "the await keyword is used to suspend the execution of the function until a promise is resolved" yes. but are you saying it's returning a promise that is *not* resolved or something else? Perhaps expand your example code to show how/where something is not working as you intend/expect.

Comment: I entered all the code.
It all starts with the generation() function.

The problem occurs, to make you understand, also for the printouts of the public keys on the screen where there are the console.logs.

In theory it should print those values ​​first and ONLY THEN launch the next function.

Comment: 1. There's already a `createWalletFull` globally defined, yet you are also defining `async function createWalletFull`.
2. You are logging before even calling any wallet creation function, that's why the logs happen first.
3. Your code does not demonstrate where (if at all) the promise is not working. Regardless of awating createWalletFull, it will likely return a resolved promise instantly because it's not doing very much.